# Why does "flex-wrap" not taking up the whole width of parent div when there is a border in parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, web-frontend

https://jsfiddle.net/51wgds8p/8/

```
:root {
    --basic-color-gray: rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.616);
    --dark-gray: rgba(88, 86, 86, 0.616);
    --basic-color-blue: rgb(0, 89, 255);
}


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: rgba(14, 22, 34);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
} 


.number {
    border: 1px solid var(--basic-color-gray);
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: var(--basic-color-blue);
    flex-wrap: wrap;    
}
 
.notes-in-board {
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```
<div class="line" id="line">
  <div class="number" id="number">
    <div class="notes-in-board">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="notes-in-board">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="notes-in-board">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="notes-in-board">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="notes-in-board">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="notes-in-board">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I remove border in `.number` , the enclosing div takes up the whole width of 60px with `dispaly:flex` and `flex-wrap: flex`. but with the border in parent div, each line only holds two child divs with 20px in width. Why is that? and how can I work around it? what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you check box-sizing:border-box style in you divs?

Comment: @AliZeinalzadeh yes.  with or without it, child divs still not taking the whole width. There should be 3 child divs in each row.

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: content-box;` to your `.number` class and it'll work as intended.

When you set it to `border-box`, the box width of `60px` will include the border width of `1px`. That is, its inside content area is reduced to `58px`, making its flex-children wrap.

To avoid this, you could either remove the fixed width from its children, or change the parent to `content-box`. See the working snippet below.

```css
:root {
  --basic-color-gray: rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.616);
  --dark-gray: rgba(88, 86, 86, 0.616);
  --basic-color-blue: rgb(0, 89, 255);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(14, 22, 34);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.number {
  border: 1px solid var(--basic-color-gray);
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--basic-color-blue);
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.notes-in-board {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="line" id="line">
  <div class="number" id="number">
    <div class="notes-in-board">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="notes-in-board">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="notes-in-board">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="notes-in-board">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="notes-in-board">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="notes-in-board">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```